# How to put 2 sources codes in Git and merge them

Tags: git, merge

Let's say there are a big java web project A from developper A and a big java web project B from developper B. Both are not under git.

To put them under Git and merge them, should I do this :

- Create a Git Repo
- Commit Project A in Repo
- Checkout Branch B from Project A
- Copy Project B to Branch B
- Commit Project B
- Switch back to master
- Merge Branch B with Master

If no what should I do, if yes is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your process is correct.

Your biggest pain point is going to be that last step - [here's the git man page on how to handle merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).